# How to share an image and test on all share options

Tags: android

I'm making a new game i need to add an help option which will share the image shown in a level and a text about the image using the :

```
Intent helpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

The user is not limited to any share option like, Facebook, twitter, Google+, MMS,... etc from user apps

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching what Intent (Broadcast Receivers) the above mentioned options are listening to. Send the intent to that then you will be able to share the content on them too.